# Is it Possible to go back initial state in sequence workflow?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

i am using series of activities .On checking up of some condition i should decide to go through initial state or to the next state.

Is it possible through the workflows.

Comment: Yes, you can define transitions between any state in a state machine workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Execution of activities within a Sequence activity is inherently linear. A State Machine activity allows Transitions that loop back, as ajawad987 noted. In a Flowchart activity, you can also connect arrows back/upward to create a loop in the logic; for branching options that enable this, you can use the FlowDecision or FlowSwitch.

If this does not answer your question, perhaps you could clarify which workflow Activity types you are using, and what kind of condition checking you need?